# How to add two number and store in array then add the previous number to latest number using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```js
var array=[num1,num2];

function number(){

    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

    for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){

        sum = num1 + num2;
        array.push(sum);
        console.log(array);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="num1">
<input type="text" name="" id="num2">

<button type="submit" onclick="number()">Click</button>
```

Hello guys, I'm Beginner in javascript how to add number and store in an array. For example, Input 1 is 5 then in Input 2 is 7 so that the answer becomes [5,7,12,19,31,50...]. using javascript. Sorry still learning javascript :)

Comment: You can get the last element with this: `var lastNum = array[array.length -1]`

Comment: Can you do it for me sorry I'm literary beginner in javascript sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You are really close to the solution.
There are many options, but the simpler would be something like this.

In the for-loop you could access the two last numbers in the array.

```
var array=[num1,num2];

function number(){

    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

    for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){

        sum = array[array.length - 1] + array[array.length - 2];
        array.push(sum);
        console.log(array);
    }
}
```

A more complex approach would be using the **Array.reduce** method. Which I recommend you to learn and understand.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = []
  ,   eNum1 = document.getElementById('num1')
  ,   eNum2 = document.getElementById('num2')
  ;
function number()
  {
  array[0] = parseInt(eNum1.value);
  array[1] = parseInt(eNum2.value);

  for(var i=1;i<=10;++i)
    {
    array[i+1] = array[i-1] + array[i]
    }
  console.clear()
  console.log(`array = [ ${array.join(', ')} ]`)
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="num1">
<input type="text" name="" id="num2">

<button type="submit" onclick="number()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from the 3rd index to do your sum like

```
function number(){

 var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
 var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

 for(var i=2;i<=10;i++){

    sum = array[i-2] + array[i-1];
    array.push(sum);
    console.log(array);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop 10 times. One solution for just adding the two numbers and the sum of them would be something like this:

```js
const arr = []

function sum() {
 
    const firstInputNum = parseInt(document.querySelector('#num1').value)
    const secondInputNum = parseInt(document.querySelector('#num2').value)
    
    arr.push(firstInputNum, secondInputNum, firstInputNum + secondInputNum)
    console.log(arr)   
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1">
<input type="number" id="num2">

<button onClick="sum()">Add numbers</button>
```

Notice that i use the `querySelector` method that must modern browsers support to get DOM elements using CSS selector style instead of the `getElementById`.